# Creating a dictionary linking each word of a text file to a list of lines where it occurs in the file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

What I want is to build a function that receives a text file as a parameter and returns a dictionary with each of the words in the text associated with the list of lines in which the word occurs in the text. This is what I came up with:

```
def dictionary(file):
    in_file=open(file, 'r')
    words=[]
    d={}
    lines=in_file.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        words=words+line.split(' ')

    for j in words:
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            if j in lines[i]:
                d[j]=i
    return d
```

However, this isn't quite what I wanted since it only shows one line index (and not in a list) where the word appears.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exactly you want ? dictionary with all words and their line number?

Comment: That's how dictionaries work, one value per key. What output were you expecting?

Comment: You can make a dict where each value is a list of numbers, if that is what you want. What is it that you want?

Comment: Alright, maybe I wasn't clear enough. What I want is to build a function that receives a text file as a parameter and returns a dictionary with each of the words in the text associated with the list of lines in which the word occurs in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing only one value of appearance for each word in your dictionary, you could store a list. This could be easily updated when another match is found:

```
def dictionary(file):
    in_file=open(ficheiro, 'r')
    words=[]
    d={}
    lines=in_file.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        words=words+line.split(' ')

    for j in words:
        if (j not in d):
            d[j] = []
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                if j in lines[i]:
                    d[j].append(i)
    return d
```

Comment: This actually creates quite a weird output, for example the key/word 'rabbit' in my text file was linked with the following value: 'rabbit.': [12, 14, 17, 12, 14, 17]. In other more frequent words, the list would be repeated quite a bunch of times.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This output was related to multiple occurrences of the same word. Each time your whole file was parsed again. Therefore the repeatings. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that should do what you are looking for, with annotations:

```
def dictionary(filename):
    # Pass the function a filename (string)

    # set up a dict to hold the results

    result = dict()

    # open the file and pass it to enumerate
    # this combination returns something like a list of
    # (index i.e. line number, line) pairs, which you can 
    # iterate over with the for-loop

    for idx, line in enumerate(open(filename)):

        # now take each line, strip any whitespace (most notably, 
        # the trailing newline character), then split the 
        # remaining line into a list of words contained in that line

        words = line.strip().split()

        # now iterate over the list of words

        for w in words:

            # if this is the first time you encounter this word, 
            # create a list to hold the line numbers within 
            # which this word is found

            if w not in result:
                result[w] = []

            # now add the current line number to the list of results for this word

            result[w].append(idx)

    # after all lines have been processed, return the result
    return result
```

Some links to the relevant functions (they wouldn't display correctly within the annotations):

[open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

[strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: Few changes and it works great. However I'm not acquainted with the notation since I'm still just a learner. What actions does for idx, line in enumerate(open(f)) perform?:                                              :

Comment: Sure, fair enough. Just updated with annotations. Hope it helps

Comment: @Joe - checking in, did this answer your question?